# Nested macros in Sweet.js

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

How can I do nested macros using sweet JS?

```
macro a {
    rule { { $e:expr } } => { }
}

macro b {
    rule { test } => { }
}
```

In this case, b isn't an expression. Can I set that `$e` can also be a `b` macro, being possible to do `a b test` instead of `a`, `b test`, that i s valid?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. `a { b test }` matches just fine.

Comment: No. It doesn't. http://sweetjs.org/browser/editor.html#macro%20a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rule%20%7B%20%7B%20$e:expr%20%7D%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Amacro%20b%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rule%20%7B%20test%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aa%20%7B%20b%20test%20%7D

Comment: Slight changes make it work http://sweetjs.org/browser/editor.html#macro%20a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rule%20%7B%20%7B%20$e:expr%20%7D%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20$e%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Amacro%20b%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rule%20%7B%20test%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20test%20+%20%22Hi%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aa%20%7B%20b%20test%20%7D